# Target _blank links not clickable in firefox?

Tags: firefox, target

Ive got a weird bug in my site.it seems that all of my target _ blank links wont click at all in firefox? i know there is a bit of an issue with target blank in firefox but these links wont click at all? i have never had this before? cleared all caches and updated firefox and still no dice?

here is my code for one specific page item the css is irrelevant to this question so i wont post that. if you want to see a live version its under discountgetaways dot co dot za

```
  <li class="span4">
<div class="thumbnail">
     <div align="center"><img class="img-rounded" src="img/graystones.jpg">
     </div>
     <h3 align="center">Grey Stones Beach House</h3>
     <h5 align="center">Langebaan</h5>
         <p>Looking for affordable beach front luxury accommodation for up to 8 people?
            Greystones Beach House in Langebaan offers fabulous winter specials with 15% off bookings of 3 nights or more.
            Normal price: R2 200 per weekend night and R1 900 per week night, <strong>less 15%!!</strong> 
            Offer excludes long weekends and school holidays<br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <button class="btn"><a target="blank" href="http://goo.gl/8XA1j">visit site</a></button></p>
    </div>
```

So specifically the link inside the button tag works in chrome just fine but absolutely nothing in firefox?

Any help would be greatly appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A inside BUTTON doesn't look like valid HTML to me, even if it works in Chrome. Can't you just put class="btn" on A?

You could try http://validator.w3.org/ and see what it says.

Comment: Nice one bro that works but breaks my css for the button? its a little longer than it was now?

Comment: What does your CSS look like?

Comment: Resolved For firefox and IE7 and 8 using the form tag and removing padding in the bootstrap css file

          <form target="_blank" action="http://goo.gl/8XA1j">
          <button class="btn" type="submit">visit site</button>
          </form>

Thanks for the help